# Video answers after a specific input

Tags: answer-set-programming

Sorry if my question is silly. I know nothing about programming but I have a doubt. Is it possible nowadays to create a program that could understand my words and give me a specific video as an answer. I mean the idea is like at the web of IKEA, where there was "a doll" that had an answer or another depending on the question asked. My idea would be something similar but the answer would be a specific previously recorded video.

Sorry again if this is just crazy but I would appreciate your answers.

Comment: Everything is possible, given enough effort.

Answer (score 1):

That IKEA girl exists on many websites. It's called a [virtual assistant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_online_assistant). Somes companies are specialized, but it's reserved to professionals. If you want a simple artificial intelligence, you can check out [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/).